# static inside React component

Tags: reactjs, static

Can anyone tell me what happens in line number 9 in the file Wizard.js here: https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/examples/wizard ? How does the unwrapping work and stuff like that?

I do understand the concept of children in React, I think, but not in this way. If I change the `<Wizard.Page>` inside `index.js` with `<div>` and remove the line 9 in `Wizard.js`, the code still work, but not if I just remove the line 9 in `Wizard.js`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line defines a very basic [functional component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components), that simply renders its children.

It is defined as a static property on the `Wizard` class, so that it is accessible through `Wizard.Page`.

The code in `Wizard.js` does not really rely on the fact that the children of the `Wizard` component are actual `Wizard.Page` components - it just assumes that the children are the different steps in the wizard:

```js
render() {
    const { children } = this.props
    const { page, values } = this.state
    const activePage = React.Children.toArray(children)[page]
    ...
}
```

That's why it still works when you used `<div>` instead of `<Wizard.Page>`: the `div` elements act as wrappers around their children too, and the code in the `render()` method will still work as intended.

But the `<Wizard.Page>` approach has several benefits:

- It makes the code in `index.js` more readable and explicit
- If needed, the `Wizard.Page` component could evolve into a more complex component, with additional logic, without requiring any change in `index.js`

Comment: I thougt it would be more readable with `<Wizard.Page>`, but I can not see what this line do: `static Page = ({ children }) => children` It seems for me that the Wizard.Page's children will be returned, and not the props to Wizard.Page, like eg. the validate-function. Is this true? I can not see how this line of code makes it possible to use <Wizard.Page> instead of div. How does the unwrapping of Wizard.Page work?

Comment: Technically, it defines a `Page` static property on the `Wizard` class. The value of the property happens to be a valid, although very simple, React functional component. This component has specific behaviour - it only render its children.

I made you a simple example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-cherry-okwub

Comment: Aha, I think I get it: It is just a wrapper and wherever you want to use/render Wizard.page, it only renders its children because of the `return children` in the static field? Cool! Thank you very much!